# How to shift h1 tag to little bit right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I type heading using html's `<h1>Heading Here</h1>` there is no space between the browser windows's left side to the heading, I want this heading to shift little bit in the right side (not in the center though) how do I do this?

Is this possible with just HTML or would have to use CSS or bootstrap?

Comment: add `padding-left`

Comment: So padding-left is used to shift element at the right side?

Answer (score 2):

`text-indent` or `padding-left` will move the text content inside its bounding box (the result is the same if you have one row and different if you have 2 or more lines of text)

Otherwise you can move the whole element, e.g.

- `margin-left: ...`,
- `transform: translateX(...)`
- `position:relative` and `left: ...`

```css
h1 {
  border: 1px #9bc solid;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.a { text-indent: 3em; }
.b { padding-left: 3em;}
.c { margin-left: 3em; }
.d { transform: translateX(3em);}
.e { position: relative; left: 3em;}
```

```html
<h1 class="a">My wonderful title</h1>
<h1 class="b">My wonderful title</h1>
<h1 class="c">My wonderful title</h1>
<h1 class="d">My wonderful title</h1>
<h1 class="e">My wonderful title</h1>
```

Comment: Or add an actual space using `h1::before {content:' ';}`

Comment: yep, there are several techniques

Comment: whole element? means if I use margin-left on a div then everything inside it would move, right>

Comment: @Jox It sounds like you're trying to decide what to use, based on information you haven't revealed here yet. If one of the techniques mentioned here doesn't work as well as another, you should tell us why.

Comment: @Jox see the code updated and pick the version that fits your needs

Comment: @Jox For example, if the h1 has a background-color, then using padding looks very different from using margin. Things like that. We don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Content moves not an element

Add `padding-left:15px` what you want;

or

bootstrap add the class `pl-*` `1,2,3,4,5`

```
<h1 class="pl-3">Heading Here</h1>
```

Element move then add `margin-left` or bootstrap class `ml-*`

Comment: how to do this with margin, can you tell please Lalji